# How do I repair a "No Route to Host" error?

Tags: 14.04, networking

I test a simple client/server program (C, BSD sockets) but get a No Route to Host message from the call to connect(). Works elsewhere - gory details:

Hardware: Older desktop (brutus) running Fedora 9, and five new Acer Aspire compact desktops running Ubuntu 14.04 LST. Acer in question is named cleo.

Notes: ping and ssh work between any two of the six nodes. Same user/password on every one of them. (brutus has independent user and files. cleo has NFS-server files, all mounted on the other four Acer nodes.)

Software: SER is started manually in foreground (or background) and waits for a connection. CLI is started manually and interacted with by user: type in a math expression like "3 + 7" which is sent to SER who returns "3 + 7 = 10" which is displayed by CLI. ^C can terminate SER. ^C is the preferred way to terminate CLI, who sends a termination request message to SER, so it quits too. (I said it was simple.)

Issue: Run CLI on (old) brutus and SER on (new) cleo - works perfectly. Run SER on brutus and CLI on cleo, and connect() says No Route to Host.

To-date: I looked at dmesg but saw no new details. I ran "route -n" based on some reports here and noticed that cleo has "0" under #hops but brutus has "1". No idea how to change that...

All 6 nodes are on a single Gigabit Ethernet LAN with a Link-sys switch. All its lights look normal.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Alex

P.S. I had a lot of trouble getting this far but posts here helped me install xinetd, nfs-common, nfs-server, and a few other goodies that I would never have uncovered by myself. I've got some experience with Linux but these problems' ("package not installed by default") solutions would have never occurred to me. Thanks to all.

Comment: you say ping works.... please show your relevant c - code with the connect part in it...

Comment: Thanks for the response, Wolfgang. Ive decided to replace the Fedora 9 install with a 32-bit version of Ubuntu 14.04. Having just gone through this install on five machines the steps are fresh in my mind and it will probably be a lot easier than trying to figure out what's missing in F9. Since the code works perfectly on all five Ubuntu machines, I'm pretty confident that it will work on the 6th.

Comment: UPDATE For the record, the problem was a missing xinetd package. I got a "yum -y" command from somewhere but since Fedora9 was too old to recognize my WiFi PCI card, I installed a 32-bit version of Ubuntu 14.04, did the SW updates and issued the "apt-get install xinetd" command. Success!